# Get facebook logged in user's ID on ASP CLASSIC

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

in a facebook app iframe tab, Is it possible, i tried with the JS SDK but then the user needs to allow that.

how can i get only his user id with classic asp?

Answer (score 0):

Your website can't get at the user's Facebook Id in any way unless the user allows it.  Period.  Thank God -- I mean Zuck.

Comment: look at the question again, i forgot important info

Comment: ok, in that case I can't help... only worked with Facebook API on sites outside of Facebook.  I'd assume that your Facebook App gets told the user ID via the link that gets passed or something... I'm sure this is documented.

Answer (score 0):

In short, When facebook contact your canvas url for displaying your tab, it set POST data that contains a signed_request parameter which contains amongst other :

a `user` field : A JSON array containing the locale string, country string and the age object (containing the min and max numbers of the age range) for the current user.

So no user id !

If you want to know more about your user, you have to go through the auth/permissions process. After that, in subsequents displays of your canvas, the `user_id` and `oauth_token` (and others) fields will be added to the POST variables.

More at : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth

This is also true for the "full app" view now that they have harmonized full apps and tab apps. The only difference now is the width of the iframe (520px for tab, 760px for full)